# Running `tsc -p .` yields "unknown compiler option" errors

Tags: typescript

Whenever I run, `tsc -p .`, it returns an error stack:

> ```
> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'checkJs'.
> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'resolveJsonModule'.
> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'noUnusedParameters'.
> error TS6047: Argument for '--target' option must be 'ES3', 'ES5', or 'ES6'.
> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'.
> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'moduleResolution'.
> ```

Only *some* of the compiler options are deemed valid, where most are not.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "target": "esnext",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "api/dist"
    },

    "include": [
        "api/src/*"
    ],

    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "api/test/*"
    ]
}
```

I'm not entirely sure as to why this happens. I was unable to find any similar issues online.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? for instance 'resolveJsonModule' is only supported from TS2.9

Comment: Similarly checkJs is 2.3 and later - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files

Comment: Currently running v4.0.2